# How React's diffing algorithm works with a list of elements?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**UPD:** **I used React Dev Tools with Highlight Updates which seems to highlight each render() method call**

I've written a simple React App which works the next way:

1. It has a button and a list of numbers
2. After clicking the button it adds a new number to the bottom of the list increased by 1 from the previous one

The problem is that **React updates all list elements each time** even when I use `key` property. I know that this problem can be solved by using PureComponents class or self-implemented `shouldComponentUpdate()`

Why React updates all list elements if they are not changed? I though that React uses special **diffing algorithm** for comparing elements and it should have worked, but now I see that it works not as I expected.

Could any body explain why React's **diffing algorithm** doesn't work in this case?

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      numbers: [] 
    }

    this.handleButtonClick = this.handleButtonClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleButtonClick() {
    const numbers = this.state.numbers;
    const length = this.state.numbers.length ;
    const newNumber = length > 0 ? numbers[length - 1] + 1 : 0;

    this.setState({
      numbers: [...numbers, newNumber]
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleButtonClick}>Add</button>
        <NumbersList numbers={this.state.numbers} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}


class NumbersList extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {
          this.props.numbers.map((number) => <NumberItem key={number} number={number} />)
        }
      </ul>
    )
  }
}

class NumberItem extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <li>{this.props.number}</li>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Are your keys unique?

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv Yes, they are. I don't think that it's a bug of my app

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zphfaoy4/ - Using dev tools in Chrome on the Elements tab I don't see any DOM changes other than new `<li>` elements being added. Either I don't understand the question or I cannot reproduce this.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv If try to use the React devtool extension and you turn on "Highlighting update" there it will show you that all elements are updated

Comment: Unfortunately React Dev Tools don't work in jsfiddle. But I am pretty sure that what the inspector shows is correct. Add a "break on subtree modifications" breakpoint on the `<ul>` and look through the process. You'll find that only the new `<li>` insertion happens. I guess React Dev Tools does something unexpected here.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv I'm tending to think that I just don't understand how React Dev Tools Highlighting works. Thanks for your help! I will try to dig deeper

Answer (score 1):

The Javascript/React side uses `shouldComponentUpdate` to determine if it should rerender.  This defaults to `true` and will rerender the component any time that there is a state change.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate

Using this rerendered virtual representation of your app, it uses this https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#the-diffing-algorithm to reconcile your virtualDOM with the real DOM

Comment: I used React Dev Tools with Highlight Updates which seems to highlight each render() method call.

Comment: The `render` method is called when `shouldComponentUpdate` returns true.  `shouldComponentUpdate` runs when state changes.  That is independent of the actual dom being updated.  The only way to affect that is to return false from shouldComponentUpdate, which should only be overridded when there is a serious performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

`this.setState({numbers[index-1]: newNumber})`?

Your code here:

```
this.setState({
  numbers: [...numbers, newNumber]
})
```

reads to me as a replacement of the numbers array and not an update of it.